# How do you npm build with Tailwind.css?

Tags: node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I have completed and basic site using Node, Tailwindcss, and Alpine js. Whenever I run a command like "npm start" or "npm build" I get an error.

```
iMac:dmMySite21 eginoj$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/eginoj/.npm/_logs/2021-02-19T03_12_40_559Z-debug.log
iMac:dmMySite21 eginoj$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/eginoj/.npm/_logs/2021-02-19T03_13_12_384Z-debug.log
```

**Here is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "y",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer")
    // ...
  ]
};
```

I know there is a build script I am missing but I can not find the correct documentation on how to add it. Everything I have tried has wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the **start** attribute in the script with the file name.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```

In your case adding a start in the package.json will resolve the issue.

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "y",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node mainjsfile.js",
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```